# Vba - Rows Property

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice of Vba.
I have been litteraly fighting all day with this bit of code:

```
Sub ComandsCompactVisualization()
    Dim x, i As Integer
    Dim CellToAnalyse As Range

    x = 2
    i = 0

    For i = 0 To 5 Step 1
    Set CellToAnalyse = Worksheets("Comandi").Cells(x + i, 2)

        If Not CellToAnalyse.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            Worksheets("Comandi").Rows("x+i:2").Hidden = True
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

I am trying to hide all the rows that in cell (x+i,2) have not got red text.
I am almost there but... Rows does not seem to accept as content Rows("x+i:2").

I obtain Runtime error 13 "Type mismatch".

If I substitute its content with Rows("2:2") row 2 is deleted but I am not any more able to hide all the other rows that do not have red text in column 2.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Anything between quotes "like this" is just a string. To perform arithmetic on x you need to do this first, then concatenate it to the other part of the string. Like this:

```
.Rows((x + i) & ":2")
```

BTW Isn't red 3..?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ComandsCompactVisualization()
Dim x as long, i As Long 'You must declare ALL variables (x was as variant in your code)
Dim CellToAnalyse As Range
dim WS as Worksheet

'x = 2  'if x is always the same value, no need to calculate it each loop
'i = 0 'numbers are initialized to be 0, strings to be "", boolean to be false.

set WS=Sheets("Commandi")

For i = 0 To 5 ' Step 1
   Set CellToAnalyse = WS.Cells(2 + i, 2) 

   If CellToAnalyse.Font.ColorIndex <> 2 Then
        CellToAnalyse.entirerow.hidden=true
        ' WS.Rows(2+i).entirerow.hidden = true is the same result
   End If

Next i

End Sub
```